# How to show each of the selected value from single select option in input tag

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript and I want to use the select option to list each selected value in the input tag.

I have tried to use javascript to show the selected value but when I select for the second time the first value dismiss and show the second selected. I was expected to show each selected value in the input tag separately without dismissing other previous selected.

```js
function getSelectedValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  document.getElementById("myValues").innerHTML = selectedValue;
}
```

```html
<select name="" onchange="getSelectedValue();" class="form-control" id="list">
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="">
```

I expected the output of
`<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="Option1">`
`<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="Option3">`

thus in the input should show

> Option1
>   Option3

Comment: i think use of jquery make it easier.

Comment: You're using `...innerHTML = selectedValue;`, thus in theory replacing the content. Replace the `=` with a `+=` and you will be appending instead. However you'll either want to use `.value` (since this is an input) or, if it is supposed to be read-only, use a `<p>` or `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Select2](https://select2.org/) jQuery plugin for that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    width: '100%'
});
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="options[]" multiple="multiple">
<option>Option1</option>
<option>Option2</option>
<option>Option3</option>
<option>Option4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new input to the div with the selected value

```js
var selectedValues = [];
function getSelectedValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  if( !selectedValues.includes(selectedValue) ){
    selectedValues.push(selectedValue);
    
    document.getElementById("myValues").innerHTML += 
    '<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="' + selectedValue + '"></br>';
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="" onchange="getSelectedValue();" class="form-control" id="list">
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
<div id="myValues">
</div>
```

Comment: this is not the correct answer, read the question before you post answer. wrong answers will be downvoted

Comment: @AkhilAravind this is how I understand the question.

Comment: @AkhilAravind and I think he can decide if its a correct answer or not

Comment: your answer is super wrong, we cannot use same Id in a document, that is a bad practice

Comment: No option for deleting a selection, incomplete answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer is what I want. @AkhilAravind

Comment: @AkhilAravind I dont know what are you talking about. if you mean "myValues" then its different, the other id is "myValue" without the "s" man and there is a difference between wrong and bad practice even though I have not done it. Anyway, I dont know why you are so angry about this. All what I have said is let him decide and as you see he wants it in different inputs. We are here to help each other as a community, no need to get angry.

Comment: @Andam I was explaining error, dont think I am angry. please understand. 
`'<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="' + selectedValue + '"></br>';`  check this line, your id is `myValue`, accourding to your solution, Id for input field is same and repeating.  now you got my point :D. be cool dude

Comment: @AkhilAravind :D

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like that if you want to use Jquery.**

```js
function getSelectedValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  
  if(selectedValue) {
  
  var html ='<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="'+selectedValue+'"> <br>';
  
  $('.inp').append(html);
  $('.default').remove();
    
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" onchange="getSelectedValue();" class="form-control" id="list">
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>

<div class="inp">
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="" class="default">
</div>
```

Comment: What if he wants to delete a selection?

Comment: then need to give option for delete.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you really expect, but I think this solution can be helpful to you. checkout the snippet.

First get the value and then append to the existing value

```js
function getSelectedValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  var _optionSelected = document.getElementById("myValue").value; 
  _optionSelected.length ? document.getElementById("myValue").value += ', '+selectedValue : document.getElementById("myValue").value += selectedValue;
  
}
```

```html
<select name="" onchange="getSelectedValue();" class="form-control" id="list">
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValue" value="">
```

Comment: you say "I dont know what you really expect" and then you tell me that Im incorrect. If you dont know, why you are telling me its incorrect

Comment: @Andam may be he was expecting like tag input in a single input box, your answer is listing item in div. check the question, he needs inside input box, not div. my answer shows result inside input box not div

Comment: Again, wrong answer. This doesn't take into account deleting a selection, plus it allows same option to be added twice.

Comment: Thank you but I want every option selected to appear in its input and not in a single input.

Answer (score 0):

Im not entirely sure I understand you 100%, but if I do i think you want to be able to see all of the selected values in the input box? That you have selected, ever! If so:

```js
var values = []

function getSelectedValue() {
  var selectedValue = document.getElementById("list").value;
  if (values.indexOf(selectedValue) === -1) { //prevents duplicate values
    values.push(selectedValue)
  }
  document.getElementById("myValues").setAttribute('value', values.join(' '))
}
```

```html
<select name="" onchange="getSelectedValue();" class="form-control" id="list">
  <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
  <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
  <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
  <option value="Option4">Option4</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="value[]" id="myValues" value="">
```